# Vue application using google maps library loses library on refresh

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js

I'm still fairly new to Vue.js but I'm building an app that uses several custom components that share data with Vuex all inside a Laravel framework.

There are a few third party .js libraries included like the google maps api.

When I make a change and rebuild `npm run dev` and load my application, all works fine.

If I refresh the page then I get errors about this line buried in one of my components:

`let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.latitude, this.longitude);`

There is that `google is undefined` so I'm guessing the library doesn't get reloaded on a browser refresh?

UPDATE:

I load the .js files in a blade template:

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')

<h1>Search</h1>
<div id="app">

<search-box
    app-id="{{ env('ALGOLIA_APP_ID') }}"
    api-key="{{ env('ALGOLIA_API_KEY') }}"
    index-name="{{ env('SCOUT_PREFIX') . env('ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME') }}"
></search-box>
</div>



@endsection

@push('scripts')
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&callback=initmap&libraries=geometry,places' async defer></script>
<script src='/js/markerclusterer.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/1.0.3/oms.min.js"></script>
@endpush
```

```

You can see this also loads the search-box component in which lives the offending line:

`let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.latitude, this.longitude);`

Comment: Can you provide some sample code on where are you declaring the usage of the 3rd party library?

Comment: It could be that it is getting loaded, but has not loaded yet when your component tries to render. In any case we will need a [mcve] to figure out what the exact problem is as with the current description we can only make vague guesses.

Comment: Thanks - I've added more information to show how I load the .js libraries. If it is a matter of the components loading first, wouldn't this also happen on the first time I load the page?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue now:

When I load the maps api script I use a callback method to initialise the map and I set a `mapLoaded` flag to use before trying to interrogate the API.

The offending bit of code was not checking for this flag.

Sorry to waste your time.